# How to create chathead and window exactly like facebook messenger?

Tags: android

Image of  the required required feature:

[image: Image of the required required feature]

I have searched a lot about this thing. 
And nothings working out.
I have found some codes but thats only for the bubble.
But I also want the window as theres in the above picture, one that has all the tabs and all.
I dont need the complete code but just for the window.

Comment: Please, include your code in the question, even if it's not what you're looking for. Take a screenshot and let people know how far you've tried. Then people can polish your solution to achieve your goal. This question is too broad so far. Also, please take two minutes to read: http://stackoverflow.com/tour and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i done the coding for the bubble. But i have no idea how to make the window which pops down when the bubble is clicked

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked this [library](https://github.com/flipkart-incubator/springy-heads)?